# botón like ajax javascript puro

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, php7

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para mi clase de base de datos y estoy haciendo un sistema de Posts
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para esto estoy implementando php principalmente, pero creo que no hay forma correcta de hacer un sistema de likes através de PHP (ósea, sin recargar la página) y estaba pensando sobre hacerlo con ayuda de Ajax y PHP que sé que se puede, hacer el llamado con javascript y envíar a PHP y desde ahí hacer las consultas y los cambios, no sé si hay una forma de hacerlo con Javacript puro, la mayoría de ejemplos que he encontrado es con Jquery, y siendo honesto, todavía no sé como dominar Jquery, todo mi proyecto lo he hecho con javascript puro y no quisiera agregar toda la libería sólo por esto.
Estaba pensando agregar la función en un Onclick, pero sé que eso no es lo más seguro que se puede hacer, no sé si hay una forma más correcta.

```
<div class="pretty p-icon p-round p-tada">
  <input type="checkbox" name="like<?php echo $pos['id_article']; ?>" onclick="like(event)" />
  <div class="state p-danger-o">
    <i class="icon fa fa-heart "></i>
    <label>Favorite</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y eh  Javascript

```
function like(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

La tabla en MySQL es así

```
CREATE TABLE `favorite` (
    `id_favorite` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_article` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id_user` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `state_favorite` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COLLATE 'utf8_spanish2_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_favorite`),
    INDEX `id_article` (`id_article`),
    INDEX `id_user` (`id_user`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish2_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=8
;
```

Todos tienen Default, excepto id_article & id_user que quisiera que fueran los que se envíen desde AJAX para trabajar con ellos, el id_user ya tiene session con $_SESSION['id_user']

No sé si haya alguien que me pueda dar una solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar esta plantilla, es la que yo uso para mi `ajax` con `js` puro y lo uso con GET.

```js
function like(e){


if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    clean = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  }else{
    clean = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  clean.onreadystatechange = function(){

  if (clean.readyState  == 4 && clean.status == 200) {  
    
      var string = clean.responseText; //aquí obtienes la respuesta del servidor que es el 'echo' de PHP

    
}

}
clean.open('GET','pagina.php?dato='+variableJS+'&dato2='+variable2JS+'...'+'&datoN='+VariableN,true);
clean.send();
}
```

En tu PHP así obtendrías los valores.

```
<?php
$_GET['dato'];
$_GET['dato2'];
?>
```

Comment: Una pregunta la carpeta de JS está en Blog>libs>JS>

Comment: Pero el PHP quiero ponerlo en Blog>user>likes ¿como le hago on el clean Open y la dirección

Comment: pon la ruta completa blog/user/likes/pagina.php

Comment: No, ya. Gracias, que pendejo. Estaba concatenando con punto como en PHP :v

Comment: Suele suceder, si te sirvió mi respuesta para solucionar tu problema no olvides marcarla como aceptada, así los demás usuarios que tengan el mismo problema sabrán por dónde empezar.

Comment: Una última cosa. Quiero que me cargue con un onload, ¿Cómo recibo true o false en el response Text n el PHP le puse que envié true ir false

Comment: Si quieres que se ejecute cuando carga la página pon esto `window.addEventListener('load', like);
function like(){}`, y en el PHP en vez de true o false, puedes imprimir un `0` que indique **false** o un `1` que indique **true**, en el response solo haces un `if(string == 1){

//entonces es verdadero
}else{
//entonces es falso
}`

Comment: Es lo que estaba haciendo, pero requiero traer el This.id para ubicarlo (lo estaba depositando en el Id)

Comment: El id del checkbox? Pero no lo puedes tomar así cargando la página, deberías de oprimir el check y ahi puedes usar el this.id, siempre y cuando tenga atributo id tu checkbox.

Comment: Pero quería que se le diera check al iniciar la página ¿o lo hago directamente con PHP?

Comment: Pues para eso puedes ponerle el atributo checked en el HTML.

Comment: Pues ya lo hice con PHP, muchas gracias en serio

Comment: De nada compañero :D